# Amortized cost for Stack Operations

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, amortized-analysis, stacks

> In this problem we consider two stacks $A$ and $B$
> manipulated using the following operations ($n$ denotes the size of $A$ and $m$ the size of $B$):
>   PushA($x$): Push element $x$
> on stack $A$.
>   PushB($x$): Push element $x$
> on stack $B$.
>   MultiPopA($k$): Pop $min(k;n)$ elements from $A$.
>   MultiPopB($k$): Pop $min(k;m)$ elements from $B$.
>   Transfer($k$): Repeatedly pop an element from $A$ and push it on $B$,
>                until either $k$ elements have been moved or $A$ is empty.

I need to find the amortized cost for the each operation using accounting method.

Comment: This gives you a potential function argument but can easily be converted to the  accounting method https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/159153/118807

Comment: [Who created this problem and where have you encountered it](/help/referencing)? What is your [answerable COMPUTER**SCIENCE** question](/help/how-to-ask)? Is there anywhere in particular you find yourself stuck? Show how far you got!

Comment: 0


I have assumed amortized cost for Push A and B as 2 for reach.
Remaining operations it will be zero except for Transfer = 2n

Can this costs be possible ?

Comment: I don't see MultiPopX($k$) take less effort than push. With every cost a multiple of 2, I'd drop that factor.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed amortized cost for Push A and B as - 2
for remaining operations it will be zero
except for Transfer - 2n

Can this costs be possibee ?

Comment: This does not answer any question. It seems an addition to your question: Use the [`Edit`](/posts/165472/edit) hyperlink centrally below the post.